# Push a pure-python module to Dask workers

Tags: dask

Is there an easy way in Dask to push a pure-python module to the workers?

I have many workers in a cluster and I want to distribute a local module that I have on my client.  I understand that for large packages like NumPy or Python I should distribute things in a more robust fashion, but I have a small module that changes frequently that shouldn't be too much work to move around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [Client.upload_file](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.upload_file) method.

```
client.upload_file('myfile.py')
```

This method will distribute the file and, if the file ends in `.py` or `.egg` will also import and reload the module on each of the workers.

Comment: What about all files under a module?

Comment: If there are 2 files under that module, 1 file may import the other one like "import module.file2". This import will break if the module structure isn't preserved during upload_file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative if you wish to deploy a package to the workers after they have started you can do something similar to this using [Client.run](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run) and  [Client.restart](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.restart)

```
def deploy_env(packages):
    conda_prefix = pathlib.Path(sys.executable).parent.parent
    res = subprocess.check_output(['conda', 'install', '-p', conda_prefix] + packages)
    return res

# Run the deploy command on all the workers
result = client.run(deploy_env, packages)

# Restart all the worker processes
client.restart()
```

After this the packages specified will be installed on all currently running workers.

This approach will not work when adding additional workers to the scheduler.