# Pushing multiple modules to Dask cluster with file structure

Tags: dask

This is almost an extension to this question [Push a pure-python module to Dask workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327802/push-a-pure-python-module-to-dask-workers)

I have a similar challenge, except the code I am trying to run is spread across multiple modules some of which come from a subdirectory. In order to keep my code reasonably well organised I have a main 'code_runner' that loads different modules from the "features" folder in order to perform a number of data processing steps.

I understand that I can load files up to the Dask cluster, but how can I do this so that the directory structure is maintained and my imports can still work like "from features import feature_1 as f1" (for example).

Alternately, if I am thinking about this incorrectly is there a better way to approach this using Dask?

Answer (score 0):

People usually deploy more complex software environments using tools like Docker, NFS, conda-pack, or some other mechanism.  The `upload_file` method is really intended as a small supplement to a full environment.  Shipping around large complex software environments may be out of scope for Dask.  We recommend relying on whatever mechanism you're using to move around your software.